# What is a good diagrammatic way to represent async event communication between two systems?

Tags: communication, event-sourcing, sequence-diagram, pubsub, data-flow-diagram

What is a good diagrammatic way to represent asynchronous event communication between two systems (the pub sub model)? I am not looking for tools but more of a representation. Is it a sequence diagram, a swim lane diagram or some other?

Comment: I think when you write "a sync", you meant "async". "Async" is short for the word "asynchronous" whose opposite is "synchronous".

Answer (score 8):

The [UML sequence diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) is well adapted to represent an interaction [between several objects](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#lifeline) (or components or, why not,systems). It has semantic to make the difference between [synchronous and asynchronous communication](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html). You may even show [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311852/3723423) in message passing (but don't abuse of it).

However for a more complex interactions between systems, you should consider [BPMN collaboration diagrams](http://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/2529/What-is-a-BPMN-Collaboration-Diagram.aspx). They were designed specifically for this purpose. They have the advantage of facilitating the representation of how each system reacts to events in a flow of related tasks, including exceptional [events](https://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/) such as time-outs and errors.

In both cases the communication is based on messages. Both allow asynchronous and synchronous communication (although synchronous requires more efforts in BPMN). But BPMN will allow the more precise and powerful [event](http://blog.goodelearning.com/bpmn/common-bpmn-modeling-mistakes-best-practices-basic-events/) diagramming you're looking for.